# I have MSSQL database table (is Identity) is NO and I need to make it auto Increment by C# code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I need to input data to SQL database table by SQL command via c# and very important to increment each row in the database (Identity increment 1 and Identity Seed 1)

but I don't know how the code is or cant I do this by my self

so, I'm looking for help that can make me passing the data with auto numbering for rows

thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use Identity=Yes?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983). What **specifically** is it you need help with? What about what you have tried isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to use **SQL Stored Procedure** then just do it and then use **ADO.NET** or **Dapper Micro ORM** to call the Stored Procedure with the needed **parameters** excluding the auto-incremented fields(parameters) as they are not needed to be inserted.

Detailed Example:
Suppose you have the following Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewEmail] @Konu NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Kimden NVARCHAR(200)
    ,@Kime NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Metin NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Ekler NVARCHAR(max)
    ,@Aktif BIT
    ,@Saat NVARCHAR(6)
    ,@Sql NVARCHAR(max)
AS
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ReportingEmails]
VALUES (
    @Konu
    ,@Kimden
    ,@Kime
    ,@Metin
    ,@Ekler
    ,@Aktif
    ,@Saat
    ,@Sql
    )
```

Your C# code:

```
public class MailEntity
{
    public int Kayit { get; set; }
    public string Konu { get; set; }
    public string Kimden { get; set; }
    public string Kime { get; set; }
    public string Metin { get; set; }
    public string Ekler { get; set; }
    public bool Aktif { get; set; }
    public string Saat { get; set; }
    public string Sql { get; set; }
}
```

The method of the insert to be:

```
//using System.Data;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;

        public void AddEmail(MailEntity mailEntity, SqlConnection connection)
        {
            //SqlConnection con = BuildSqlConnection();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandTimeout = 600000000;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "ReportingInsertNewEmail";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Konu", mailEntity.Konu);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kimden", mailEntity.Kimden);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kime", mailEntity.Kime);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Metin", mailEntity.Metin);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ekler", mailEntity.Ekler);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aktif", mailEntity.Aktif);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saat", mailEntity.Saat);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sql", mailEntity.Sql);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
```